# Awk: Strip all characters except whitelisted ones from a column

Tags: shell, awk, strip

```
   awk 'length($1)==3 && length($2)==3 {print $1, $2 "\t", $5}' file.txt
```

I am trying to print the column with only one character.

It could be either A or B or C or D , negate every thing else in $5.

$5 in file.txt is

```
112C
222F
B212
F2334
C23
A123
```

I want the output to be

```
 C

 B

 C
 A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all characters *except* `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` from `$5`, use `gsub(/[^ABCD]/, "", $5)`

Applied to your command:

```
awk 'length($1)==3 && length($2)==3 { 
  gsub(/[^ABCD]/, "", $5);
  print $1, $2 "\t" $5
}' file.txt
```

Comment: what if i want to do it be $5 and $6

Comment: what if i want to do it with $5 and $6 too . Thanks

Comment: @maria: Glad to hear it. Looking at your other questions, allow me this recommendation: please try to improve the clarity of your questions and state all requirements up front, as specifically as possible. Include _representative_ sample input and _matching_ expected output. Ill-defined and shifting requirements lead to frustration in those willing to help.

Comment: Sure another quick question what if I was using NF-5 instead of $5

Comment: @maria: Just use the expression as the field, in parentheses: `$(NF-5)`

Answer (score 0):

awk 'length($1)==3 && length($2)==3 {match($5, /A|B|C|D/, arr); print $1, $2 "\t", arr[0]}' file.txt